# mongodb filter inside 4 nested array and get the brother result

Tags: mongodb

I try to get value from 4 nested documents.

I'd try with 2 filters and I can't get the value.

this is the structure of my nested documents.
I have the Id of the main object. the ID of the Note and the FileID.
I need to get only the FileName of my FileID.

```
{
    "_id":  ObjectId("0000"),
    "Details": {
        "Notes": [
            {
                _id:  ObjectId("2222"),
                Files: [
                    {
                        "FileID" : ObjectId("3333333"),
                        "FileName" : "image.png" 
                    },
                    {
                        "FileID" : ObjectId("666666"),
                        "FileName" : "pdf.pdf" 
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                _id:  ObjectId("1111"),
                Files: [
                    {
                        "FileID" : ObjectId("44444"),
                        "FileName" : "image.png" 
                    },
                    {
                        "FileID" : ObjectId("5555555"),
                        "FileName" : "pdf.pdf" 
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have some start code that I can't get the results:

```
 db.getCollection('Notes').aggregate([
    {
          $match: { "Details.Notes.Files.FileID": ObjectId("44444") }
    },
        {$project: {
            "Details.Notes.Files.FileName": 1,
               files: {$filter: {
                input: '$Details.Notes.Files',
                as: 'file',
                cond: {$eq: ['$$file.FileID', 
               ObjectId("44444")]}
            }}

        }}
     ])
```

Answer (score 1):

please test this solution:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  $match: {
    "Details.Notes.Files.FileID": ObjectId("54759eb3c090d83494e2d804")
  }
},
{
  $unwind: "$Details.Notes"
},
{
  $unwind: "$Details.Notes.Files"
},
{
  $match: {
    "Details.Notes.Files.FileID": ObjectId("54759eb3c090d83494e2d804")
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    "FileName": "$Details.Notes.Files.FileName",
    "_id": 1
  }
}])
```